# jQueryUI autocomplete - place search results adjacent to input in DOM

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, dom

I'm using [jQueryUI's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), but for the following reasons I'd like to move the search results into the DOM next to the input tag that's doing the search.

It's easiest to see [this on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2B9f/), but essentially code demonstrating the issue looks like so:

```
<html>    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" /> 

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> google.load("jquery", "1.4");
   google.load("jqueryui", "1.8");  </script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#X").autocomplete({
        source: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
   .B {   display: none;    }
   .A:hover .B { display: block;  }
</style>
</head>  <body>

Hello
<div class='A'>
select:
  <div class='B'>
    <input id='X' />
  </div>
</div>
World

</body>   </html>
```

The problem is that when one hovers their mouse over an autocomplete option the element containing the autocompleting input tag is no longer in 'mouseover'ed' and per the CSS rules the input tag disappears with its container. This is not the desired behaviour; I'd like to keep the input tag visible when highlighting the autocomplete selections.

I would hope and expect that it'd be possible to move the autocomplete elements to the DOM next to the input tag (i.e. `x = $("#X"); x.append(x.autocomplete('widget'))`), and therefore the CSS rules would keep the input and its parent visible. Alas, this doesn't work.

I'd be grateful for any thoughts on how to achieve this mixture of CSS and jQueryUI.

Thank you.

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like something that should be supported natively in jQuery UI!  Anyway, here's something that I think will work:

```
$("#X").autocomplete({
    source: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'],
    open: function($event, ui) {
        var $widget = $("ul.ui-autocomplete");
        var $input = $("#X");
        var position = $input.position();

        $("div.B").append($widget);

        $widget.css("left", position.left + $input.width());
        $widget.css("top", position.top);       
    }
});
```

This positions the widget by moving the auto-complete box to the right of the input, and solves the rollover problem by appending the widget to the same `<div>` the `<input>` belongs to.

http://jsfiddle.net/U2B9f/1/

**Edit:** This solution will work, especially for older versions of jQuery UI, but Brian's answer below is a better solution.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, Andrew. :) I'd think this is something jQuery UI should do natively, too!

Comment: In case it is indeed unintended behaviour, I've created a ticket for this issue: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6724

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer that could be preferable to Andrew Whitaker's (and per the ticket I started: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6724):

Using the `appendTo` option of [`autocomplete`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js), i.e.

```
$("#X").autocomplete({
  appendTo: $(".B"),
  source: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'],
});
```

You can see [this in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2B9f/2/).

Comment: This is awesome, I never would have known this option existed!  I guess you still have to do a bit of trickery to get the box to show up somewhere besides directly underneath the targeted `<input>`

Comment: @Andrew: It's great isn't it? As well, there's no trickery for positioning the box, either -- the latest version of `autocomplete` also takes a `position` argument -- see https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js!